# How to resolve this issue in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am working on **vue@1.0.28** version. I trying to use **v-if, v-else-if.....** but not work.

Example:

```
<div v-if="type === 'A'">
  A
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'B'">
  B
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'C'">
  C
</div>
<div v-else>
  Not A/B/C
</div>
```

It prints all condition values.

Does vuejs support v-elseif blocks in version 1?

Comment: Vue@1.0.28 does not support `v-else-if`

Answer (score 1):

As per official vue documentation **v-else-if** is added in **2.1.0+** version and you are using old version of vue.please update your vue version.
Refer this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else-if